# Newcommand executed in align throwing missing $ inserted

Tags: math-mode, macros

I'm trying to write a newcommand which inserts a colorbox with the input given to it. This works for regular text and math input, but within a math environment it throws a "missing $ inserted" error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,color}



% I've got several environments for conditional rendering, here's one
\newenvironment{filled}{\ifdefined\filledflag\else\setbox0\vbox\fi\bgroup}{\par\egroup}

% my command
\newcommand{\clozecontentinline}[1]{
    \begin{filled}
        \colorbox{white}{#1}
    \end{filled}
}

\begin{document}

\def\filledflag{}
%% working
\begin{align*}
    a=b+\colorbox{white}{$c$}
\end{align*}

%% not working
\begin{align*}
    a=b+\clozecontentinline{c}\\
    a=b+\clozecontentinline{$c$} % both won't work, missing $ inserted for both
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please make a test file not disconnected fragments, it makes it a lot easier to answer. (I did it this time)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought about it twice, will decide otherwise next time. Sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case shown (the flag is defined) you were inserting `\par` in math mode which is not allowed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,color}


\newbox\zzbox
% I've got several environments for conditional rendering, here's one
\newenvironment{filled}{\relax\ifdefined\filledflag\else\setbox\zzbox\vbox\fi\bgroup}
{\ifdefined\filledflag\else\par\fi\egroup}

% my command
\newcommand{\clozecontentinline}[1]{%
    \begin{filled}
        \colorbox{white}{#1}
    \end{filled}%
}

\begin{document}

\def\filledflag{}
%% working
\begin{align*}
    a=b+\colorbox{white}{$c$}
\end{align*}

%% not working
\begin{align*}
    a=b+\clozecontentinline{c}\\
    a=b+\clozecontentinline{$c$} % both won't work, missing $ inserted for both
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The vbox here though is rather suspect, the contained paragraph will be broken to lines `\textwidth` wide?  Also `align` should never be used without alignment points (`&`) so it is not clear what the intention of this code is, but it runs without error now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, my code now works. I would've wished that the error would have been "\par not allowed" instead of the "missing $ inserted" error...The align was just an example, forgot about the  `&`. I have no clue what you are talking about in the comments though.

Comment: @VanC actually ignore the comments just me and campa chatting, I will delete mine) the error comes from inside tex so latex cannot change it, it is designed to catch the case you have a paragraph of text `blah blah $x=y  blah more text ...`   where you forgot the closing `$` and the error is caught at the blank line (not explicit `\par`) at the end of the paragraph.

Comment: You don't have to delete your comments, I guess it was just an improvement to the code. There is no particular reason for the `\vbox`, I've found this code somewhere on the interwebs. It is very sad that the errors are limited this way. This is driving me crazy, not to say students starting to use latex :-( Worse than c++ errors for beginners.

Comment: @VanC the vast majority of errors you get from latex come from tex code (and so can be changed from within tex) but some low level syntax errors are compiled in to the program and are what they are. This is one of those.